# How do I set custom search engines in Android?

Tags: browser, search

For years now, on every browser I own, Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Internet Explorer, I've assigned `w` as a shortcut/keyword to the custom search engine `http://www.google.com/search?q=site:wikipedia.org+%s&btnI`.  That is, I just type `w android comparison` to jump to the befitting wikipedia article.  I use many, many other custom searches.

Is there a way to set this up on Android?  Not necessarily with the stock browser?

Comment: Have you tried Firefox Mobile? My phone doesn't support Firefox Mobile, but these are the kind of stuffs that Firefox Mobile might be able to do. Opera Mobile and Opera Mini also has custom search, although, AFAICT, not using the address bar but a separate search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with [Firefox Mobile](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/). The search plugins from `addons.mozilla.com` can be installed directly in Firefox mobile.

If the search plugins from `addons.mozilla.com` don't cut it, Shortmarks.com lets you make your own search plugins to save on your Firefox install. [This guide](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/860061) might help.

Comment: I'm afraid, the shortmarks solution no longer works...

Answer (score 2):

##### With Firefox:

- Tap the menu button next to the address bar:
- Tap Settings.
- Go to Search.
- Go to Add Search Engine.
- Add a name and a search address (e.g. `Wikipedia` and  `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s`)
  Repeat the last two steps for each engine you want to add.

Then when you'll tap the address bar you'll be able to choose the engine you like by tapping on it.

The best way to use this feature is through the Firefox widget, which automatically proposes the engines to use.

##### With Chrome

I found an app that does the job (it can work with any browser), but unfortunately, it is not free if you add more than 5 custom engines.

install [SearchBar Ex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devhomc.search), then add search engine with `ADD` > `Search` > `Custom Search`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of apps that will either give you a Wikipedia search widget on the home screen, or add Wikipedia as an option to the built-in search widget's drop-down selection. Have a look at a few of these: https://market.android.com/search?q=wikipedia+search

Comment: Sorry I have many, many, many such custom searches. I only used Wikipedia as a relatable example in my question, but there are no search widget in the market for many, many many of my custom searches.

Comment: @WilliamC fair enough, you might want to mention in the question that Wikipedia's only an example rather than the main focus of the question.